# How to combine and use multiple Next.js plugins

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I would like to use `css` and `scss` in `next.js`app.

I have `next.config.js` in my project.

This configuration is for `scss`:

```
// next.config.js
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');

module.exports = withSass({
    cssModules: true,
    cssLoaderOptions: {
        importLoaders: 1,
        localIdentName: "[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
    }
})
```

I don't know how to combine `const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');` with my current config.

I would like to use custom config for `scss` (from my code snipet).

Can someone help me configure next for `css` and `scss` modules?

I tried:

```
// // next.config.js
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');

module.exports = withCSS(withSass({
    cssModules: true,
    cssLoaderOptions: {
        importLoaders: 1,
        localIdentName: "[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
    }
}))
```

**Not working...**

Answer (score 38):

You can use `next-compose-plugins` and combine multiple next.js plugins as follows:

```
// next.config.js
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [
    [withSass, { /* plugin config here ... */ }],
    [withCSS,  { /* plugin config here ... */ }],
  ],
  {
    /* global config here ... */
  },
);
```

Comment: How can this be done without the compose library?

Answer (score 18):

This can also be done pretty easily ***without*** the `next-compose-plugins` library.

It's arguably a bit clearer too:

```js
// next.config.js
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');

module.exports = (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
  const plugins = [
    withSass({ /* Plugin config here ... */ }),
    withCSS({ /* Plugin config here ... */ }),
  ];
  return plugins.reduce((acc, next) => next(acc), {
    /* global config here ... */
  });
};
```

I discovered this whilst complaining here: [Source](https://github.com/hashicorp/next-mdx-enhanced/issues/18#issuecomment-859167393)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the proper solution is described [here](https://github.com/cyrilwanner/next-compose-plugins/issues/59#issuecomment-1192523231), as far as you use next:12.3.1 or upper version

```
module.exports = (_phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
const plugins = [withStaticImport, withBundleAnalyzer, withCustomWebpack]
return plugins.reduce((acc, plugin) => plugin(acc), { ...defaultConfig, ...config })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update for 2023:**

Consider using [`next-recompose-plugins`](https://github.com/IdkMan2/next-recompose-plugins) which provides a clean and easy API for Next.js's plugins configuration and composition.

Here is an example:

```js
const config = new Config(async () => {
    await something();
  
    return {...};
  })
  .applyPlugin((phase, args, config) => {
    return plugin1(config);
  }, 'plugin-1')
  .applyPlugin((phase, args, config) => {
    return plugin2(config);
  }, 'plugin-2')
  .applyPlugin((phase, args, config) => {
    return plugin3(config);
  }, 'plugin-3')
  .build();
```