# nextjs config merging module export

Tags: javascript, next.js

I want to have both of these module exports, can someone tell me how to merge:

```js
const path = require("path");
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');


module.exports = {
target: "serverless",
webpack(config) {
config.resolve.modules.push(path.resolve("./"));
return config;
}
};

module.exports = withCSS(withSass());
```

Tried multiple ways described on stackoverflow and my own ideas unfortunately didn't work. The first module is for absolute paths and the second for bootstrap. If you have general suggestions how to get the result even easier I would appreciate it.

Comment: Did you see this issue? Might be helpful https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/issues/34

Comment: Have a check on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60177847/how-to-combine-and-use-multiple-next-js-plugins

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const withCss = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withImages = require('next-images');

const nextConfig = {
    ... // webpack configs if you have
    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [
    [withImages],
    [withCss],
    [
      withSass, // if you have other options go this way
      {
        cssModules: true,
        cssLoaderOptions: {
          localIdentName: '[path]___[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  nextConfig,
);
```