# Multiple plugins Next.js

Tags: next.js

Is there a better way to use multiple plugins using `next.js` ?

I am currently doing the following but It looks very messy.

```
const withLess = require('@zeit/next-less');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');

module.exports = withCSS(withLess({
    cssModules: true,
    cssLoaderOptions: {
        importLoaders: 1,
        localIdentName: "[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
    }
}))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine and use multiple Next.js plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60177847/how-to-combine-and-use-multiple-next-js-plugins)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks