# How to combine several plugins inside next.config.js file?

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

When I add ["next-videos" loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-videos?activeTab=readme) to the `next.config.js` it works perfectly as long as `module.exports` goes the last one:

```
module.exports = withVideos()
```

On the other hand, it breaks another instance of `module.exports` that located above:

```
module.exports = {
   images: {
     domains: ['cdn.shopify.com'],
   },
};
```

Basically, it overwrites every previous `module.exports`. What are the rules for combining these exports? I guess I need to put them under one module but what are the rules to do it? I'm messing up with syntax and every try to relocate it under one `module.exports` ends with new errors

**Just to sum up the questions:**

1. **What are the rules of combining modules inside single export and how I can combine it with all my previous module.exports?**
2. **Do I really need to leave "webpack(config)" part that duplicates the identical part above inside next.config?** I gathered it from different sources and now trying to figure out how does it really work

```js
webpack(config) { 
  config.module.rules.push(
```

Contents of the
**next.config.js**:

```js
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withImages = require('next-images');
const withVideos = require('next-videos');
const withBundleAnalyzer = require('@next/bundle-analyzer')({
    enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true',
});

// next.config.js
module.exports = withPlugins(
    [[withImages], [withSass], [withCSS], [withVideos]],
    {
        plugins: ['postcss-import', 'tailwindcss', 'autoprefixer'],
        serverRuntimeConfig: {
            mySecret: 'secret',
            secondSecret: process.env.SECOND_SECRET, // Pass through env variables
        },
        publicRuntimeConfig: {
            // Will be available on both server and client
            staticFolder: '/public',
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /.jsx?$/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
                },
                {
                    test: /\.jsx?$/,
                    use: ['babel-loader', 'astroturf/loader'],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
                    loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000',
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|otf|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif|webm)$/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 100000,
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    test: /\.mp4$/,
                    use: 'file-loader?name=videos/[name].[ext]',
                },
                {
                    test: /\.style.js$/,
                    use: [
                        'style-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: { importLoaders: 1 },
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: { parser: 'sugarss', exec: true },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
        webpack(config) {
            config.module.rules.push(
                {
                    test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|otf|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 100000,
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    test: /\.style.js$/,
                    use: [
                        'style-loader',
                        'css-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: { importLoaders: 1 },
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: { parser: 'sugarss', exec: true },
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader'],
                },
            );
            withBundleAnalyzer({});
            return config;
        },
    },
    {
        images: {
            domains: ['cdn.shopify.com'],
        },
    },
    withVideos(),
);

module.exports = {
    extends: 'airbnb-base',
    rules: {
        'arrow-body-style': 0,
    },
};

module.exports = {
    images: {
        domains: ['cdn.shopify.com'],
    },
};

module.exports = withVideos();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine and use multiple Next.js plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60177847/how-to-combine-and-use-multiple-next-js-plugins)

Comment: you can find a solution for the current problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74037680/13370462)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You seem to be mixing several configs incorrectly into your Next.js config file.

##### Without `next-compose-plugins`

There's no need to use `next-compose-plugins`. Next.js plugins are built to be chainable, you can nest each plugin call inside the next one, and pass the actual config object on the last call. Your `next.config.js` file should also only have a single `module.exports`.

```js
// next.config.js

// Omitting requires for simplicity
 
module.exports = withImages(
    withSass(
        withCSS(
            withVideos(
                withBundleAnalyzer({
                    images: {
                        domains: ['cdn.shopify.com']
                    },
                    serverRuntimeConfig: {
                        mySecret: "secret",
                        secondSecret: process.env.SECOND_SECRET
                    },
                    publicRuntimeConfig: {
                        staticFolder: "/public"
                    },
                    // From here everything that's Webpack-related
                    webpack(config) {
                        // Add your custom Webpack configs
                        return config;
                    }
                })
            )
        )
    )
);
```

##### With `next-compose-plugins`

If you're using [`next-compose-plugins`](https://github.com/cyrilwanner/next-compose-plugins), it should roughly follow this structure:

```js
// next.config.js

// Omitting requires for simplicity
 
module.exports = withPlugins(
    [withImages, withSass, withCSS, withVideos, withBundleAnalyzer], // All next plugins go here
    // Below is the main Next.js config object
    { 
        images: {
            domains: ['cdn.shopify.com']
        },
        serverRuntimeConfig: {
            mySecret: "secret",
            secondSecret: process.env.SECOND_SECRET
        },
        publicRuntimeConfig: {
          staticFolder: "/public"
        },
        // From here everything that's Webpack-related
        webpack(config) {
            // Add your custom Webpack configs
            return config;
        }
    }
);
```

---

Finally, the following config belongs to your ESlint config file, and not Next.js config.

```js
// .eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
    extends: 'airbnb-base',
    rules: {
        'arrow-body-style': 0,
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue when I was trying to access global css fils from node packages into a Next JS Page, after many trials I solved by changing the following:

When there is need of using multiple plugins or a normal `JSON` config with a plugin, you need to wrap the original config within plugin.

In your case,

```
module.exports = withVideos(
images: {
     domains: ['cdn.shopify.com'],
   },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Update for 2023

Although the question is a bit out of date as nowadays Next.js supports most of these plugins functionalities out of the box, the plugin composition topic is still relevant.

That's why I recommend you to try [next-recompose-plugins](https://github.com/arklanq/next-recompose-plugins), the successor of `next-compose-plugins`. This package provides a clean and easy API for Next.js's plugin configuration and composition.

In your case it would look like:

```js
const config = new Config({
  // ... your base config goes here
})
  .applyPlugin((phase, args, config) => {
    return withBundleAnalyzer({/* options */})(config);
  }, '@next/bundle-analyzer')
  .applyPlugin((phase, args, config) => {
    return withVideos(config);
  }, 'next-videos')
  .applyPlugin((phase, args, config) => {
    return withImages(config);
  }, 'next-images')
  .applyPlugin((phase, args, config) => {
    return withCSS(config);
  }, '@zeit/next-css')
  .applyPlugin((phase, args, config) => {
    return withSass(config);
  }, '@zeit/next-sass')
  .build();
```