# How to combine withPlugins with internatioinalization config in a next.config.js file

Tags: internationalization, next.js, module.exports

I have the following code in my next.config.js

```
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const optimizedImages = require('next-optimized-images');

module.exports = withPlugins([optimizedImages], { target: 'serverless' });
```

and now I need to add the following config to the file, combining with the plugin

```
i18n: {
    locales: ["en", "es"],
    defaultLocale: "en",
  },
```

I have tried the following,

```
const nextConfig = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en", "es"],
    defaultLocale: "en",
  },
};

module.exports = withPlugins([
[optimizedImages, {
    target: 'serverless'
    },
  ],
nextConfig,
])
```

and restarted the server, but I have not been successful ...

Comment: Does this answer your question [How to combine several exports inside one module (module.exports) inside next.config.js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604469/how-to-combine-several-exports-inside-one-module-module-exports-inside-next-co)? Move `target: 'serverless'` to your `nextConfig` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Next.JS are you using? I faced the same problem and it was fixed by updating to +10.0.0.

You can see on the i18n documentation on Next that this is the minimum version.

Next.js has built-in support for internationalized (i18n) routing since v10.0.0. You can provide a list of locales, the default locale, and domain-specific locales and Next.js will automatically handle the routing.

More info: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing

Answer (score 0):

#### Update for 2023

The presented method of using plugins is no longer appropriate.

Please have a look at the successor of `next-compose-plugins` which is [next-recompose-plugins](https://github.com/arklanq/next-recompose-plugins). This package provides a clean and easy API for Next.js's plugins configuration and composition.

Here is a sneak peek:

```js
const config = new Config(async () => {
    await something();

    return {...};
  })
  .applyPlugin((phase, args, config) => {
    return plugin1(config);
  }, 'plugin-1')
  .applyPlugin((phase, args, config) => {
    return plugin2(config);
  }, 'plugin-2')
  .applyPlugin((phase, args, config) => {
    return plugin3(config);
  }, 'plugin-3')
  .build();
```

I highly recommend this package because it allows us to apply plugins seamlessly, the plugin application is less error prone, and the final code looks clean and consistent.