# How to combine Next.js config setting?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have following config settings:

```js
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: [
      "ticket-t01.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com",
      "media.istockphoto.com",
    ],
    deviceSizes: [320, 375, 450, 540, 640, 750, 828, 1080, 1200, 1920],
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  poweredByHeader: false,
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/",
        destination: "/hu",
        permanent: true,
      },
    ];
  },
};

const withBundleAnalyzer = require("@next/bundle-analyzer")({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === "true",
});

module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer({});
```

but clearly first `module.exports` is not take into account. How could I combine them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine several exports inside one module (module.exports) inside next.config.js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604469/how-to-combine-several-exports-inside-one-module-module-exports-inside-next-co)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const withBundleAnalyzer = require("@next/bundle-analyzer")({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === "true",
});

module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer({
  images: {
    domains: [
      "ticket-t01.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com",
      "media.istockphoto.com",
    ],
    deviceSizes: [320, 375, 450, 540, 640, 750, 828, 1080, 1200, 1920],
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  poweredByHeader: false,
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/",
        destination: "/hu",
        permanent: true,
      },
    ];
  },
});
```