# How can I import next packages into next.config.js without overwriting entire export object?

Tags: next.js

How can I import next packages into next.config.js without overwriting entire export object?

I keep seeing a repeated pattern of configuring next.js through next.config.js that is not consistent with its (config.js) documentation. It involves assigning a single import to module.exports.

For example, extract from here: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/using-mdx

```
Require the package and configure to support top level .mdx pages. The following adds the options object key allowing you to pass in any plugins:

// next.config.js

const withMDX = require('@next/mdx')({
  extension: /\.mdx?$/,
  options: {
    remarkPlugins: [],
    rehypePlugins: [],
  },
})
module.exports = withMDX({
  pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'md', 'mdx'],
})
```

The general pattern for next.config.js from https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/introduction is to assign config within an object.

```
const nextConfig = {
  /* config options here */
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

My question is how do I configure next.js to use mdx *and* other configuration if the MDX function in this example overwrites module.exports with a single function?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to combine several exports inside one module (module.exports) inside next.config.js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65612556/1870780)? You can chain several Next.js plugins and pass the config object to the innermost plugin call.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `next.js` but from the looks of it you could just merge the MDX-config with your custom options using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals):

```
const withMDX = require('@next/mdx')({
  extension: /\.mdx?$/,
  options: {
    remarkPlugins: [],
    rehypePlugins: [],
  },
});

const nextConfig = {
  /* config options here */
};

module.exports = { 
  ... withMDX({
     pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'md', 'mdx'],
  }),
  ... nextConfig
};
```

Comment: @Laurence: Any feedback?