# Setup next.config.js file for a pwa app and next/bundle-analyzer

Tags: webpack, next.js, bundle

This is my next.config.js file and I want to use next/bundle-analyzer

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const withPWA = require("next-pwa")({
  dest: "public",
  register: true,
  skipWaiting: true,
  // put other next-pwa options here
});


const nextConfig = withPWA({
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  images: {
    domains: ["*************"],
  },
  // put other next js options here
});

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Now the docs says that I need to make some changes in the next.config.js file to include env vars

```
const withBundleAnalyzer = require('@next/bundle-analyzer')({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true',
})
module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer({})
```

My question is how can I add this code into my existing next.config.js file

Comment: Next.js plugins are built to be chainable. You can do `withBundleAnalyzer(withPWA({ ... }))`. See [How to combine several plugins inside next.config.js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604469/how-to-combine-several-plugins-inside-next-config-js-file).

Comment: This comment should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This methods return a config object , try this code :

```
module.exports = {...withPWA({}) , ...withBundleAnalyzer({})}
```

Comment: just asking, will pwa code be evaluated with Bundle Analyzer?  I thought it should be inside that. or we dont need to analyze pwa code with Bundle Analyzer ?

Comment: I used ```next-compose-plugins```, is this code correct-

```module.exports = withPlugins([withPWA, withBundleAnalyzer], nextConfig);```