# Image hostname not showing when I Intergrate sentry with nextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, sentry

I am trying to add image source in withSentryConfig wrapper which is in the next.config.js however I keep getting this error

> Error: Invalid src prop (https://example.com/bucket/media/images/7xyz.jpg) on `next/image`, hostname "example.com" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`

I was expecting not see the error but it has persisted.

Tried looking solutions with no success at all. Below is what I have tried

```js
const {withSentryConfig} = require('@sentry/nextjs');
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const optimizedImages = require('next-optimized-images');

const moduleExports = withPlugins([
  [optimizedImages, {
    images: {
      domains: ['example.com'],
    },
  }]
], nextConfig);

const SentryWebpackPluginOptions = {
  ...
};

module.exports = withSentryConfig(moduleExports, SentryWebpackPluginOptions);
```

Comment: is `domains` a valid attribute? It seems like you might actually want `imagesPublicPath`? 
https://github.com/cyrilwanner/next-optimized-images#imagespublicpath

Comment: Your `next/image` config needs to go into the `nextConfig` object. See [How to combine and use multiple Next.js plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60177847/how-to-combine-and-use-multiple-next-js-plugins).